# Rails 4 validates_confirmation_of not firing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I know I must be missing something simple.  I have a model that contains a validate_confirmation_of.  I know it works in my model (I've tested it using the console) but for some reason, it seems the confirmation field on the form isn't linking into my model correctly and so the model thinks the confirmation field is blank and thus skips the validate.

**Model**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: { suspended: 0, pending_validation: 1, pending_setup: 2, registered: 3, unknown: 99 }

  EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\Z/i

  validates :first_name, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 255 }
  validates :last_name, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 255 }
  validates :email_address, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 255 }, :uniqueness => true, :format => { :with => EMAIL_REGEX }, :confirmation => true
  validates :country_code, :presence => true

end
```

**View**

```
<%= form_for @person, url: { action: 'create' } do |f| %>

  <fieldset class="registration">

    <legend>Your Information</legend>

      <div class="group column-1">
        <%= label_tag('First Name') %> <span class="required">*</span>
        <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control', :tabindex => 1 %>

        <%= label_tag('Display Name') %>
        <%= f.text_field :display_name, class: 'form-control', :tabindex => 3 %>
      </div>

      <div class="group column-2">
        <%= label_tag('Last Name') %><span class="required">*</span>
        <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control', :tabindex => 2 %>

        <%= label_tag('Country') %> <span class="required">*</span>
        <%= f.collection_select :country_code, Country.order(:name), :iso_code, :name, { :include_blank => true }, { :class => 'form-control', :tabindex => 4 } %>

      </div>

      <div class="column-full">
        <%= label_tag('Email Address') %> <span class="required">*</span>
        <%= f.text_field :email_address, class: 'form-control', :tabindex => 5 %>

        <%= label_tag('Confirm Email Address') %> <span class="required">*</span>
        <%= f.text_field :email_address_confirmation, class: 'form-control', :tabindex => 6 %>
      </div>

      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <%= check_box_tag 'chkTerms'  %>
            I accept the <%= link_to 'Terms & Conditions', '/pages/terms' %> <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="button-options">

        <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
        <%= link_to 'Cancel', '/pages/home', class: 'link-button-cancel' %>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
def create
    @person = Person.new(register_params)
    @person.status = 'pending_validation'

    if @person.save
       render('submit')
    else
       render('register')
    end

end

private
    def register_params
      params.require(:person).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email_address, :display_name, :country_code)
    end
```

As you can see, in my view I have a "email_address_confirmation" text_field.  I created it the way I created all the other fields and they all work fine so for the life of me I can't figure out what is wrong with the code.  But when I submit the page, no matter what I put in the confirmation field, the confirmation validate never fires.

In case it matters, I'm using Rails 4.2.0 and Ruby 2.1.5p273.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this in your model:

```
validates :email_address_confirmation, presence: true
```

According to [Rails guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#confirmation):

> This (confirmation) check is performed only if `email_confirmation` is not `nil`.

Also make changes in your controller's method `register_params`, you miss `email_address_confirmation` field in permit parameters:

```
def register_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email_address, :email_address_confirmation, :display_name, :country_code)
end
```

Comment: Sadly I already tried that.  If I add that to the model, then I just get an error that email_address_confirmation is blank even if I provide something to the email_address_confirmation field.  As I stated, it seems as though the email_address_confirmation text field in the view is not wiring up correctly to the model but I don't know why.

Comment: I've added the controller code as well. Is it possible the problem is with the "registration_params" i've created? I don't want the confirmation to be permitted in the post back (i.e. I don't want it to repopulate the field) so I didn't include it in the .permit() statement but is that incorrect?

Comment: You need `:email_address_confirmation` in permit list too

Comment: thanks that worked.  Can you post that as the answer (so that its readily noticeable) and I'll accept it?